# Query and Group by

Tags: mysql, sql

i have some meetings with date and hours and examinator, on these meetings, i put a candidate. The candidate must pass the exam.

i have a table like that:

```
Exam | Meeting | Niche | Date     | Hour | Examinator | idCandidate
Math |    1    |   1   |2014-06-28|08:00 |    John    |     1
Math |    1    |   2   |2014-06-28|08:20 |    John    |     0
Math |    5    |   3   |2014-06-28|13:00 |    John    |     0
Math |    2    |   4   |2014-06-28|08:00 |    Will    |     0
Math |    2    |   5   |2014-06-28|08:20 |    Will    |     0
Math |    3    |   6   |2014-06-29|08:00 |    John    |     11
Math |    3    |   7   |2014-06-29|08:20 |    John    |     0
Math |    6    |   8   |2014-06-29|14:00 |    John    |     0
Bio  |    4    |   9   |2014-06-28|08:00 |    Bruce   |     0
Bio  |    4    |   10  |2014-06-28|08:20 |    Bruce   |     0
Bio  |    4    |   11  |2014-06-28|08:40 |    Bruce   |     0
```

What i would like is:

```
Exam |   Date   | Examinator | Nb Free Candidate
Math |2014-06-28|  John      |         2
Math |2014-06-28|  Will      |         2
Math |2014-06-29|  John      |         2
Bio  |2014-06-28|  Bruce     |         3
```

Actually, i want to display the number of free niche (meeting) order by exam, date and examinator.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Comment: I tried: select Exam, Meeting, Niche, Date, Hour, Examinator, SUM(IF(idCandidate = 0, 1,0)) AS 'Nb Free Candidate' from niche where idCandidate=0 group by meeting order by Exam ASC, Date ASC, Examinator ASC

Comment: and i get: math|2014-06-28|John|1 but i must have 2 the meetin number 5 is not in.

Comment: Sorry actually i have: math|2014-06-28|John|1 and math|2014-06-28|John|1 i have 2 lines for the same date, if i make a groupby on the date, it will group with Bio at the same date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for this GROUP BY query:

```
SELECT Exam, `Date`, Examinator, COUNT(*) AS nb_free_candidate
FROM tablename
WHERE idCandidate = 0
GROUP BY Exam, `Date`, Examinator
```

If your Date columns contains both date and time, you should use this instead:

```
SELECT Exam, DATE(`Date`), Examinator, COUNT(*) AS nb_free_candidate
FROM tablename
WHERE idCandidate = 0
GROUP BY Exam, DATE(`Date`), Examinator
```

Comment: That's what i did. And i have the result i shown in the comment.

Comment: @Alexking2005 date and hour are on two different fields? or just one?  If it's just one, you need to GROUP BY Exam, DATE(`date`), Examinator

Comment: I added what you propose, same result.

Comment: @Alexking2005 it looks okay to me http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16538/3 can you reproduce your problem with a fiddle?

Comment: i simplified my table, actually, there is 3 tables linked.

Comment: Finally, i rewrited my query and it works. I don't know why because i made exactly what you've done. Thanks a lot.